# Applying Filter in VBA with data including Single Quotes

Tags: ms-access, filter, vba

I've been trying to get a simple filter to work on a form where it applies filters based on two columns in my Access DB.

```vb
Private Sub cmb_Name_AfterUpdate()  
Me.cmb_WorkCity.Requery  
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Employee Name]='" & Me.cmb_Name.Column(0) & "' And [Movement Type]='" & Me.cmb_Name.Column(1) & "'"  
End Sub
```

There are two instances in the current test data where the Employee Name has a single quote e.g. O'Malley for instance. This results in a 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Replace()` to substitute two single quotes for each one single quote in employee name.

```vb
Private Sub cmb_Name_AfterUpdate()
Dim strFilter As String
Me.cmb_WorkCity.Requery
'DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Employee Name]='" & Me.cmb_Name.Column(0) & "' And [Movement Type]='" & Me.cmb_Name.Column(1) & "'"
strFilter = "[Employee Name]='" & Replace(Me.cmb_Name.Column(0), "'", "''") & _
    "' And [Movement Type]='" & Me.cmb_Name.Column(1) & "'"
Debug.Print strFilter ' <- view in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , strFilter
End Sub
```